# Structuring a JSON array with objects

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, array, node.js

I have a JSON array or literal (passes through JSON.parse).

Requirement: an array of tasks which contains operations which are key/value pairs.

Array of tasks > Array of operations (array of operations at times will contain duplicate key/value pairs)

```
[
    [
          {
            resize: [1200, 1200]
          }, {
            moveTo: "dest/nick"
          }, {
            rename: "{base}-12.{ext}"
          }, {
            toWeb: true
          }, {
            rename: "{base}.{ext}"
          }
        ], [
          {
            resize: [1000, 1000]
          }, {
            rename: "{base}-10.{ext}"
          }
        ]
      ]
```

The code works and I simply want to know if there is a **better** way of doing this. I had to wrap the individual operations with `{}` so that the duplicate keys wouldn't overwrite each other.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would replace `{ resize: [1200, 1200] }` with `{ operation: 'resize', parameters: [1200, 1200] }`. This is more verbose, but easier to maintain/read. This way it's eligible for extension (maybe you want to add identifiers later?). The same can be done for the tasks.

Other than that there's not a lot to say. I find the indentation not easily readable, but that's just style. I'd prefer:

```
[
    {
        name: "I'm task one",
        operations: [
            {
                operation: "resize",
                parameters: [1200, 1200]
            },
            {
                operation: "moveTo",
                parameters: ["dest/nick"]
            },
            {
                operation: "rename"
                parameters: ["{base}-12.{ext}"]
            },
            {
                operation: "toWeb",
                parameters: [true]
            },
            {
                operation: "rename",
                parameters: ["{base}.{ext}"]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "I'm task two",
        operations: [
            {
                operation: "resize",
                parameters: [1000, 1000]
            },
            {
                operation: "rename",
                parameters: ["{base}-10.{ext}"]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Also note that the value of the parameters is an array, even if it has one value.